# Change column names after merging multiple data frames into one in R

Tags: r, merge, plyr

After merging multiple data frames into one, I would like to know how to change the column headers in the master data frame to represent the original files that they came from. I merged a large number of data frames into one using the code below:

```
library(plyr) 

dflist = list.files(path=dir, pattern="csv$", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE) 
import.list = llply(dflist, read.csv) 
Master = Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="Hours"), import.list)
```

I would like the columns that belonged to each original data frame to be named by the unique ID that the original data frame/ csv file is named by (i.e. aa, ab, ac). The unique IDs in the filenames comes immediately before a low line ("_") so I can isolate them using the code below. However, I am having trouble now applying this to column headers. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
filename = dflist[1]
unqID = strsplit(filename,"_")[[1]][1]
```

Comment: My general approach would be modify the column names prior to merging. I might use `mapply` or `mlply`, passing both the file names and the data frames and then modify all the column names not equal to Hours.

Comment: @ joran: Thanks, I was hoping to avoid having to do this, but maybe it is the easiest way!

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function in your `llply` call to and have `read.csv` assign names.
or just rename them after reading them in and before merging @joran suggested

```
#First get the names
filenames = dflist
#I am unsure about the line below, as I
unqID = lapply(filenames,function(x) strplit(x,"_")[1])
names(import.list) <- paste("unqID", names(import.list),sep=".") #renaming the list items
```

And then merge using your code

Comment: @ infominer: thanks but I'm having trouble getting this to work. I just get a list with one "unqID" and then NAs. Any suggestions?

Comment: Whoops! I just edited the code and this should work. I was doing `strsplit` over filenames, whereas I should have been doing it over `x`. Let me know if this works

Comment: no, it still doesn't work. I think that it is something to do with the fact that `strsplit(x, "_")[1]` returns the whole path name before the "_" rather than just the unique ID. Thanks anyway. I may just alter the colnames prior to merging.